# How to run an Azure CLI Bash script in PowerShell?

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-cli

I installed Azure CLI. I can use it on either CMD or PowerShell, but I prefer PowerShell.
The tutorial commands that are present in the documentation are for Azure CLI with Bash. How do I run these commands in PowerShell?

For example:

```
az group create \
  --name myResourceGroup \
  --location "Central US"
```

won't work in PowerShell because `\` is not a continuing character in PowerShell and the commands are required to be a single line. Hence, I need a workaround to run Bash scripts in PowerShell.

Answer (score 1):

You can run Azure CLI commands in PowerShell like:

```
az group create `
   --name myResourceGroup `
   --location "Central US"
```

The back-tick (`) symbol is the PowerShell line-continuation character that allows you to continue a command on multiple lines.